# Using document.getElementById() inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<div id="com_22">
   <a onclick="delete(22);">delete entry</a>
</div>
```

and the javascript code:

```
function delete(url){
   var tupu = document.getElementById("#com_"+url+"");
   alert(tupu);
}
```

the problem is I'm having a `null` alert
I want to get the id

```
document.getElementById("#com_22");
```

How I can solve it

**update**

this is my code:

```
    function confirmDel(url){
        $(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/files/assets/php/ajax/blog-stream.php?act=del',
            data: 'url=' + url ,
            success: function(h){
                var status = h.status
                if (status == "si" ) {
                $("#com_"+url+"").fadeOut("slow");

                }
            }    
        });
        });

  }
```

the code excecutes so well except for the id didnt fade out
$("#com_"+url+"").fadeOut("slow"); <--- no working

Comment: `delete` is a reserved keyword in javascript, and should not be used as a function name

Comment: @adeneo: it should not even be possible.

Comment: is just an example the rea function is dcoment(url){

Comment: `document` is not reserved, it's just a bad idea. Come up with better names !

Comment: And it should be noted that you're doing it wrong, you should be using `addEventListener`, then it would be trivial to use `this.parentNode` to get what you want.

Comment: even if it's an example use proper function name, and dont forget to validate one of the answer beyond ;)

Comment: Your second example is a completely different issue. Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

See :: [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById), that should have been:

```
function delete_something(url){
    var tupu = document.getElementById("com_"+url);
    alert(tupu);
}
```

btw, try avoiding use of js pre-defined names as function name see:: [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the hash when you're selecting by `id`. You're not using `jQuery` or `querySelector`.

```
var tupu = document.getElementById("com_"+url);
```

There is also no need to concatenate the empty string there at the end so I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

The function getElementById gets the element ID as a string, not a CSS-style selector. Change to:

```
var tupu = document.getElementById("com_"+url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '#' from within the bracket.

Answer (score -1):

As can be extracted by javascript levels:

```
[{"file": ". m3u8" in this page: http: //ivm.antenaplay.ro/js/embed_aplay_fullshow.js? id = 6eI6sLVBfOL
```